# How come application-<profile>.properties is not loading when profile is set?

Tags: spring-boot

I have `application-dev.properties` and `application-local.properties` in the root of my class path. Inside the properties files are my datasource properties. But they are not being loaded even though we start the app with

`java -Dspring.profiles.active=local -jar myJarApp.jar`

Thanks

Comment: 'Not being loaded?', is there an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the argument as shown below:

```
$ java -jar xyz.jar --spring.profiles.active="dev"
```

Instead of using the -D flag.

Alternatively, you can set the following environment variable in your console/prompt, and then run the `java -jar xyz.jar` without passing any parameters

```
export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
```

That should work.

Reference:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: I think it should work, but isn't. Only way for us to tell is that Liquibase is trying to create data in an in-memory database, whereas the datasource properties in the "local" profile application-local.properties is pointing to an on machine MySQL database. Thanks for the response, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: The "" around dev wasn't necessary. And our issue in the end was that we had two jars both with application-local.properties files in the class path and Spring Boot won't use both, just only one of them, so I had to rename my second one to application-dao-local.properties and run via --spring.profiles.active=local,dao-local

Answer (score 0):

Beware of hyphens in profile names.

In my case Spring Boot 2.3.2 would select the profile `local-docker` when running

`java -jar  -Dspring.profiles.active=docker target/main-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

But it would not select the associated properties file `application-local-docker.properties` for some reason. I reverted to using a profile name without hyphen and this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to run it directly from maven

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run \
  -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=PROFILE_NAME"
```

Example:

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run \
  -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"
```